# Why does let-defined atom provide a different result?

Tags: clojurescript, core.async

I try to deasync some js-calls using clojure script. If I let the atom in the deasync function itself there is a suprising result:

```
(let [result (atom nil)
      timeout (atom 10)]
  (go
    (let [async-result (<p! (js/Promise.resolve 42))]
        (swap! result (constantly async-result))
        (js/console.log @result)))
  (while (and (nil? @result)
             (pos? @timeout))
    (do (debug @result)
        (debug @timeout)
        (swap! timeout dec)))
  @result)
 
--- output is ---
null
10
...
null
1
42
nil
```

If I define the atom outside the result is as intended:

```
(def result (atom nil))
 
(let [timeout (atom 10)]
  (go
    (let [async-result (<p! (js/Promise.resolve 42))]
        (swap! result (constantly async-result))
        (js/console.log @result)))
  (while (and (nil? @result)
             (pos? @timeout))
    (do (debug @result)
        (debug @timeout)
        (swap! timeout dec)))
  @result)

--- output is ---
42
42
```

Can someone declare the difference?
I think using a namespace global atom is not quite a good idea for a deasync function ...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write a "deasync" function, if by that you mean writing a function that "blocks" to wait for an async result. JavaScript is single-threaded so if you block in a loop to wait for an async result that loop will prevent the async work from ever happening.

The result in your program above will always be that it loops 10 times while the result is `nil` and then eventually yield control to let the queued microtask execute the `go`.

I suspect that you just maybe tried to run this from the REPL and did not redefine the `result` atom after one test run. So in the first pass it was `nil` but then got set to `42`. On the second run it then starts with 42 and your loop never loops. You can easily verify this by "labeling" your results. So instead of `(js/console.log @result)` you use `(js/console.log "go-result" @result)`. You'll see that you'll always get the loop result first and then the `go-result`.

BTW if you just want to set a specific `atom` value just use `reset!` instead of `swap!` with `constantly`, eg. `(reset! result async-result)`.

Comment: thought the io-request and it's callback function would have an own thread. Do you know a good description for browsers and nodejs threading model and io based async handling?

Comment: There is only one thread. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0 is a good summary for some details.